# Twisted and symlink in twisted/python/lockfile.py

Tags: python, twisted, symlink, vxworks

Im trying to port twisted on VxWorks. But it doesnt support symlink.
That means i have an ImportError: cannot import name symlink.

My questions are:
* For what does Twisted need symlink?
* Is there anyway to avoid the use of symlink?
* Is there any other solution or alternative to make Twisted run without symlink?

Best regards.

Comment: `grep -inr symlink twisted/`?

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks are used in the implementation of `lockfile.FileSystemLock()`, which is documented like this:

```
class FilesystemLock:
    """
    A mutex.

    This relies on the filesystem property that creating
    a symlink is an atomic operation and that it will
    fail if the symlink already exists.  Deleting the
    symlink will release the lock.
```

So what you need to do is implement that functionality in some other way that VxWorks supports. There are one or two other uses of `symlink` in `twisted.conch`, but they don't appear to be critical; mostly ways to make a symlink when SSH-ing into a Unix system.